# creating mocks for controller method with Rspec in rails

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, integration-testing, bdd

Can someone help me create mocks for the following code. I want to add a controller method in existing controller by following name and want to test its behavior to a movie class containing title, director, rating etc as table instances. Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with BDD commands to use here.

```
describe MoviesController do
  describe "#find_same_director" do
    before :each do
      fake_movies = [mock('movie1'), mock('movie2')]        
    end
    context "with invalid attributes" do 
      it "flashes no such director message" do
        flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
      end 
      it "redirects to the index method" do 
        response.should redirect_to movies_path
      end 
    end
    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "calls model method to find all movies" do 
        movie = Movie.find_with_director, {:director => 'George Lucas'}
        get :show, id: @fake_movies 
        assigns(:movie).should eq(@fake_results) 
      end 
      it "renders the #find_same_director view" do 
        get :find_same_director, id: @fake_movies
        response.should render_template :find_same_director 
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you noticing that you are trying to test different things at different test cases? (the first contexts you aren't executing the action  "get :x", the last ones you are doing "get :show"

First of all you should think about the behavior of your code, so, i can think of two contexts (what kind of situations do you have in this case):

```
  # with valid parameters(for e.g.: i should pass the right data, before this context i must create the data for the text).
  # with invalid parameters(for e.g: the parameters passed to the GET request should not be existent on the system).
```

Then you should think about what happens when this contexts are active.

```
  context "with valid parameters" do 
    it "should return the other movies of the same director, and assign it to the @movies"
    it "should render the template of the #find_same_director page"
  end 
  context "with invalid parameters" do
    it "should redirect to the movies_path"
    it "should put a flash message that the director is invalid"
  end
```

After you think about the test cases do you have to think about how to implement them, i'll give you a hint:

```
it "should return the other movies of the same director, and assign it to the @movies" do
  # THINKING ABOUT BDD HERE YOU SHOULD THINK OF THIS CODE SECTIONS AS FOLLOW:
  # GIVEN ( OR THE CONDITIONS FOR THE ACTION HAPPEN)
  @director = Director.new
  movies = [Movie.new, Movie.new]
  @director.movies = movies
  # HERE ILL FIX THE VALUES SO I CAN USE IT ON MY EXPECTATIONS
  Director.stub!(:find).with(@director_id).and_return(@director)
  # WHEN, THE ACTION HAPPENED
  get :find_same_director, :id => @director_id
  # THEN THE EXPECTATIONS THAT SHOULD BE MATCHED
  assigns(:movies).should == @director.movies
end
```

For a more real experience with tests i recommend you to watch the screencasts: http://destroyallsoftware.com/